# USB DUAL CDC endpoints for transferring data

Tags: usb, stm32, composite, cdc

I have emulated two VCPs with only one USB Device. I can send data in one VCP that has the following Endpoint Address.

```
#define CDC_IN_EP    0x81  /* EP1 for data IN */
#define CDC_OUT_EP   0x01  /* EP1 for data OUT */
#define CDC_CMD_EP   0x82  /* EP2 for CDC commands */
```

I would like to know if it's possible to send data in the other VCP with other Endpoint Address like:

```
#define CDC_IN_EP3   0x83  /* EP3 for data IN */
#define CDC_OUT_EP3  0x03  /* EP3 for data OUT */
#define CDC_CMD_EP4  0x84  /* EP4 for CDC commands */
```

My problem is that addresses others than 0x81 don't allow me to send data over the second VCP. I'm using two CDC interfaces Full-Speed. Normally we can use seven endpoints with CDC_FS and that's what I'm trying to do... I have six Endpoints: three for each VCP and the seventh is Endpoint 0 for configuration.

Have I missed something in the Endpoints Configuration or in the Composite Device Descriptors?

```
/* USB CDC device Configuration Descriptor */
__ALIGN_BEGIN uint8_t USBD_CDC_CfgFSDesc[USB_CDC_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ] __ALIGN_END =
{
    /* Configuration Descriptor */
    0x09,   /* bLength: Configuration Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_CONFIGURATION,  /* bDescriptorType: Configuration */
    USB_CDC_CONFIG_DESC_SIZ,      /* wTotalLength:no of returned bytes */
    0x00,
    0x04,   /* bNumInterfaces: 4 interface */
    0x01,   /* bConfigurationValue: Configuration value */
    0x00,   /* iConfiguration: Index of string descriptor describing the configuration */
    0xC0,   /* bmAttributes: Self powered */
    0x32,   /* MaxPower 100 mA */

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // IAD0
    0x08,   // bLength: Interface Descriptor size
    0x0B,   // bDescriptorType: IAD
    0x00,   // bFirstInterface
    0x02,   // bInterfaceCount
    0x02,   // bFunctionClass: CDC
    0x02,   // bFunctionSubClass
    0x01,   // bFunctionProtocol
    0x02,   // iFunction

    /* Interface0 Descriptor */
    0x09,   /* bLength: Interface Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: Interface */

    /* Interface descriptor type */
    0x00,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
    0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
    0x01,   /* bNumEndpoints: One endpoints used */
    0x02,   /* bInterfaceClass: Communication Interface Class */
    0x02,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: Abstract Control Model */
    0x01,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: Common AT commands */
    0x00,   /* iInterface: */

    /* Header Functional Descriptor */
    0x05,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x00,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Header Func Desc */
    0x10,   /* bcdCDC: spec release number */
    0x01,

    /* Call Management Functional Descriptor */
    0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x01,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Call Management Func Desc */
    0x03,   /* bmCapabilities: D0+D1 */
    0x01,   /* bDataInterface: 1 */

    /* ACM Functional Descriptor */
    0x04,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x02,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Abstract Control Management desc */
    0x02,   /* bmCapabilities */

    /* Union Functional Descriptor */
    0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x06,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Union func desc */
    0x00,   /* bMasterInterface: Communication class interface */
    0x01,   /* bSlaveInterface0: Data Class Interface */


    /* Endpoint 2 Descriptor */
    0x07,                         /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,       /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_CMD_EP,                   /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x03,                         /* bmAttributes: Interrupt */
    LOBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),
    0xFF,                         /* bInterval: */
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*Data class interface descriptor*/
    0x09,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: */
    0x01,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
    0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
    0x02,   /* bNumEndpoints: Two endpoints used */
    0x0A,   /* bInterfaceClass: CDC */
    0x00,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: */
    0x00,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: */
    0x00,   /* iInterface: */

    /*Endpoint OUT Descriptor*/
    0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,               /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_OUT_EP,                           /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x02,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
    LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
    0x00,                                 /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */

    /*Endpoint IN Descriptor*/
    0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,               /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_IN_EP,                            /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x02,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
    LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
    0x00,                                 /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */

    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    // IAD1

    0x08,   // bLength: Interface Descriptor size
    0x0B,   // bDescriptorType: IAD
    0x02,   // bFirstInterface
    0x02,   // bInterfaceCount
    0x02,   // bFunctionClass: CDC
    0x02,   // bFunctionSubClass
    0x01,   // bFunctionProtocol
    0x02,   // iFunction

    /* Interface1 Descriptor */
    0x09,   /* bLength: Interface Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: Interface */
    /* Interface descriptor type */
    0x02,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
    0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
    0x01,   /* bNumEndpoints: One endpoints used */
    0x02,   /* bInterfaceClass: Communication Interface Class */
    0x02,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: Abstract Control Model */
    0x01,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: Common AT commands */
    0x00,   /* iInterface: */

       /*Header Functional Descriptor*/
    0x05,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x00,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Header Func Desc */
    0x10,   /* bcdCDC: spec release number */
    0x01,

    /*Call Management Functional Descriptor*/
    0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x01,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Call Management Func Desc */
    0x03,   /* bmCapabilities: D0+D1 */
    0x03,   /* bDataInterface: 1 */

    /*ACM Functional Descriptor*/
    0x04,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x02,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Abstract Control Management desc */
    0x02,   /* bmCapabilities */

    /*Union Functional Descriptor*/
    0x05,   /* bFunctionLength */
    0x24,   /* bDescriptorType: CS_INTERFACE */
    0x06,   /* bDescriptorSubtype: Union func desc */
    0x02,   /* bMasterInterface: Communication class interface */
    0x03,   /* bSlaveInterface0: Data Class Interface */

    /*Endpoint 2 Descriptor*/
    0x07,                         /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,       /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_CMD_EP4,                  /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x03,                         /* bmAttributes: Interrupt */
    LOBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_CMD_PACKET_SIZE),
    0xFF,                         /* bInterval: */
    /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    /*Data class interface descriptor*/
    0x09,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_INTERFACE,  /* bDescriptorType: */
    0x03,   /* bInterfaceNumber: Number of Interface */
    0x00,   /* bAlternateSetting: Alternate setting */
    0x02,   /* bNumEndpoints: Two endpoints used */
    0x0A,   /* bInterfaceClass: CDC */
    0x00,   /* bInterfaceSubClass: */
    0x00,   /* bInterfaceProtocol: */
    0x00,   /* iInterface: */

    /*Endpoint OUT Descriptor*/
    0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,               /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_OUT_EP3,                          /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x02,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
    LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
    0x00,                                 /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */

    /*Endpoint IN Descriptor*/
    0x07,   /* bLength: Endpoint Descriptor size */
    USB_DESC_TYPE_ENDPOINT,               /* bDescriptorType: Endpoint */
    CDC_IN_EP3,                           /* bEndpointAddress */
    0x02,                                 /* bmAttributes: Bulk */
    LOBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),  /* wMaxPacketSize: */
    HIBYTE(CDC_DATA_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE),
    0x00                                  /* bInterval: ignore for Bulk transfer */
};
```

Comment: Does anyone have the answer please ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the STM32 USB device library. When you modify or add a new endpoint address in the configuration descriptor, you also have to set the endpoint address in the PMA (packet memory area). You can do that in the `USBD_LL_INIT` block with the `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig` function:

```
USBD_StatusTypeDef  USBD_LL_Init (USBD_HandleTypeDef *pdev)
{ 
  /* Init USB_IP */
  /* enable USB power on Pwrctrl CR2 register */
  HAL_PWREx_EnableVddUSB();
  /* Link The driver to the stack */
  hpcd_USB_FS.pData = pdev;
  pdev->pData = &hpcd_USB_FS;

  hpcd_USB_FS.Instance = USB;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.dev_endpoints = 8;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.speed = PCD_SPEED_FULL;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.ep0_mps = DEP0CTL_MPS_8;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.phy_itface = PCD_PHY_EMBEDDED;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.Sof_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.low_power_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.lpm_enable = DISABLE;
  hpcd_USB_FS.Init.battery_charging_enable = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_PCD_Init(&hpcd_USB_FS) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x00 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x18);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x80 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x58);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x81 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0xC0);  
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x01 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x110);
  HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig((PCD_HandleTypeDef*)pdev->pData , 0x82 , PCD_SNG_BUF, 0x100);  
  return USBD_OK;
}
```

After that I could use the new endpoints for data transfer.

Comment: There is no `HAL_PCDEx_PMAConfig` for STM32H743, do you have any clue why and what to do instead? Just not doing it, causes the device to be recognized as configured, but no data can be transferred!

Comment: @Davide the STM32H7xx devices use HAL_PCDEx_SetRxFiFo() and HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo() API instead since their USB peripheral hardware is different from other STM32 chip families.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to change endpoint #s for a legacy CDC driver on an embedded (host) platform, but couldn't figure out why the device driver was only able to send a single Tx packet. The Fifo setup had to be changed, as @MichaelAnsolis indicated.  I ended up using the `CDC_IN_EP` to automatically determine the transmit endpoint:

`HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, (CDC_IN_EP & 0x07), 0x174);`